# Assign the present window of the screen as a main window for accessing the elements

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

**What am I doing**

I am doing some automation test cases in iOS. For this I am using Instruments .

Now first of all I am making Object Repository for the Application so that I don't have to  write the code again and again.

**My Problem**

But I have some reference problem in window reference .

For example

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow();
```

We have put this code in library.

Now when I am taping on some button then he goes to another window . Here I am not rewriting the whole code thats why I have used this function . Now when it goes to another window after push or any effect the window refer to only old window.

**What I Need Here**

Since I am creating a library . I don't want to rewrite the code again , Is there any why where I can find the window that is now on the screen , or any approach that replace the window whenever I am using the case where tab bar is there and **window** always refers to the screen which is the first one. is there anything where I can replace that **window** after tapping ?